# Jquery Find exact DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is my Html code where I want to select only next element of selected checkbox

```
<tr class="" role="row">
<td class="e-rowcell e-templatecell" role="gridcell" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="XAxisrowCheckbox">
</td>
<td class="e-rowcell e-hide" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">0</td>
<td class="e-rowcell" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">Location ID</td>
</tr>
<tr class="e-alt_row" role="row" aria-selected="true">
<td class="e-rowcell e-templatecell e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="XAxisrowCheckbox">
</td>
<td class="e-rowcell e-hide e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">1</td>
<td class="e-rowcell e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">Location Name</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery Code

```
 $(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {

     $(".XAxisrowCheckbox").parent().next(this).css('background-color','red');

});
```

but the problem is it is applying background color to all td regardless of selected

what I am getting is 
[image]

What I expect is to change only this element which is selected
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its best to use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) for this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {
    $(this).closest('td').css('background-color','red');
});
```

It reads much more nicely than `parent` and `next`, and should you need to you could chain on a `find` statement as well. For instance:

```
$(this).closest('td').find('a').css('color','red');
```

This is essentially saying "Work your way up the dom tree until you find the first `td` wrapping the clicked element, then go down again until you find all `a` elements"

> EDIT : Actual Code Which Works after workaround for me

```
$(this).closest('td').next().css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: a little bit of work around but this worked for me thank you

Comment: probably you have a typo in `closeset`

Comment: @simon yup that was a typo mistake I corrected it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead

```
$(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {

     $(this).parent().next().css('background-color','red');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the this parameter in the next function an put it in the main selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {
    $(this).parent().next().css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

Your html,

```
<table>
    <tr class="" role="row">
        <td class="e-rowcell e-templatecell" role="gridcell" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="XAxisrowCheckbox">
        </td>
        <td class="e-rowcell e-hide" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">0</td>
        <td class="e-rowcell" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">Location ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="e-alt_row" role="row" aria-selected="true">
        <td class="e-rowcell e-templatecell e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="XAxisrowCheckbox">
        </td>
        <td class="e-rowcell e-hide e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">1</td>
        <td class="e-rowcell e-selectionbackground e-active" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">Location Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Create class called `red`,

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Simply apply class when Checkbox is checked

```
$(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {     
    $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("red", this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://Fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {

    $('.XAxisrowCheckbox input:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().next(this).css('background-color','red');

     });

});
```